# Custom resizable control flickering

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, gdi+

So I have a resizable control which I'm using `WM_NCHITTEST` to resize. I have double buffered the control and I'm drawing a border. However, when resizing, I get medium flickering issues.
Here's the code for drawing:

```
if (_cachedPen == null)
{
    _cachedPen = new Pen(BorderColor, VisibleBorderWidth);
}
Rectangle clientRectangle = ClientRectangle;
if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Left) == BorderSides.Left)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(_cachedPen, clientRectangle.X, clientRectangle.Y, clientRectangle.X, clientRectangle.Height);
}
if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Right) == BorderSides.Right)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(_cachedPen, clientRectangle.Width - VisibleBorderWidth, clientRectangle.Y, clientRectangle.Width - VisibleBorderWidth, clientRectangle.Height);
}
if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Bottom) == BorderSides.Bottom)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(_cachedPen, clientRectangle.X, clientRectangle.Height - VisibleBorderWidth, clientRectangle.Width, clientRectangle.Height - VisibleBorderWidth);
}
if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Top) == BorderSides.Top)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(_cachedPen, clientRectangle.X, clientRectangle.Y, clientRectangle.Width, clientRectangle.Y);
}
```

And for resizing:

```
case WM_NCHITTEST:
{
    Point pos = PointToClient(new Point(m.LParam.ToInt32()));
    if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Left) == BorderSides.Left && pos.X < PhysicalBorderWidth)
    {
        m.Result = new IntPtr(HTLEFT);
    }

    if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Bottom) == BorderSides.Bottom && pos.Y > Height - PhysicalBorderWidth)
    {
        m.Result = new IntPtr(HTBOTTOM);
    }

    if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Right) == BorderSides.Right && pos.X > Width - PhysicalBorderWidth)
    {
        m.Result = new IntPtr(HTRIGHT);
    }

    if ((BorderSides & BorderSides.Top) == BorderSides.Top && pos.Y < PhysicalBorderWidth)
    {
        m.Result = new IntPtr(HTTOP);
    }
    return;
}
case 0x0014:
    return;
default:
    base.WndProc(ref m);
    break;
```

Note that `SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer | ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint | ControlStyles.UserPaint | ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);` is on. However, when resizing, I get light-medium flickering. Is there any way to solve this?

Just to note, it happens even when I don't cache the `Pen` objects.

The painting is just called from `OnPaint`. The custom control just inherits from `Control`.
The definition of BorderSides is as follows:

```
[Flags]
internal enum BorderSides
{
    None = 0,
    Left = 1,
    Right = 2,
    Top = 4,
    Bottom = 8
}
```

And here are the constants:

```
private const int WM_NCHITTEST = 0x0084;
private const int HTBOTTOM = 15;
private const int HTLEFT = 10;
private const int HTRIGHT = 11;
private const int HTTOP = 12;
```

This is for a docking control. It doesn't have a graphic background, and I intend to inherit from it. It will host controls. I'm testing all 4 border sides, and all have slight flickering issues.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's the control flickering?  It might be the parent container that is not redrawing itself correctly in response to the control being resized.  Have you tried enabling double buffering on the form as well?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure, as the parent (a Form for testing) is also double buffered

Comment: I just tried nesting the control into another double buffered control, but to no avail.